# Why does [IO.DirectoryInfo]".\" not return the current directory?

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am using [IO.DirectoryInfo] in parameter validations extensively, and it turns out to be a Very, Very Bad Thing.

See here:

```
PS C:\pathsuppressed>> echo ([IO.DirectoryInfo]".\")

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                                                                      
d-r--         29.7.2014     17:06            Desktop
```

No matter what my current directory is, it states I'm in Desktop. Really?

What would be the right way to do the same? What 'type' can I use to mark that a parameter is a path in PowerShell scripts?

**Addendum:**

Seems the PowerShell ties '.' to a certain directory, at shell launch, instead of the one where I currently am. What might possibly be behind this thinking? (Microsoft is good in making excuses for PowerShell anomalies)

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `[Environment]::CurrentDirectory`?

Comment: In this case, it seems to be C:\Windows\system32

Comment: Ok, zdan has the crux of it. Powershell is doing the default conversion for a string which calls the constructor for `DirectoryInfo` which takes a string and this passes the path to `Path.GetFullPath` which uses `Environment.CurrentDirectory` for '.' because it has no knowledge of powershell.

Answer (score 3):

It's because the .NET runtime is using the current working directory of the powershell process and not the current location in the powershell shell.

To demonstrate:

```
# C:\temp> [System.IO.Directory]::SetCurrentDirectory("c:\windows")

# C:\temp> [IO.DirectoryInfo]".\"

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                  
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                  
d----         7/29/2014  10:44 AM            windows                                                                               

# C:\temp> [IO.DirectoryInfo]"$pwd"

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                  
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                  
d----         7/23/2014   3:16 PM            temp
```

To get the `DirectoryInfo` of the current powershell location, just use `get-item`:

```
# C:\temp> get-item ".\"

    Directory: C:\

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                  
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                  
d----         7/23/2014   3:16 PM            temp
```

Comment: Thanks, this explanation sounds reasonable. My actual use case is trying to declare that a script parameter is supposed to be a directory, and I was using [IO.DirectoryInfo] for that. Should I simply refrain from that and do something stupid s.a. [String] instead?

Comment: @akauppi Ah well that's a more interesting question. You should probably ask that instead, someone might have an answer.

Comment: If any Microsoft people are reading this, you could make the Powershell process's current directory mirror what the prompt does. You're advertising PS as an easy .NET compatible tool, but e.g. here there's a gap between the two world. Which I fell into.

Comment: I checked the official prototype of Test-Path and it uses String for its parameter. Thus, so shall I. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @akauppi The problem is that Powershell supports a broader definition of a 'path' than the .NET framework APIs do. The current path in the shell can be a registry key (eg. try `cd HKLM:\Software`), for example. I agree, however, this is a huge gotcha that people fall into all the time and something should be done about it.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps in solving your problem

```
[IO.DirectoryInfo](Resolve-Path ".\").Path
```

Comment: It would, in the case of this question. However, it would not solve the underlying problem of declaring a function parameter to be a path. A user would be able to give a relative string, and I cannot require them to do the above cast in calling the cmdlet. Valuable comment though so +1.